# Access SQL: Duplicate rows based on quantity

Tags: sql, ms-access

I am quite new in SQL, and I want to ask your help to find a 'general' solution about my problem described below:

I have a table like: (table name: test)

```
ID  | Item  | Qty  
1   | apple | 3
2   | peach | 2
```

I want to find a solution, that makes me a result like:

```
Item 
apple
apple
apple
peach
peach
```

Is there any way to handle this in Access SQL?